# What is the meaning of red/green exclamation icon on a github issue?

Tags: github

Github issues have a red/green exclamation-mark icon. What is the difference between the red & green?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Green** - opened issue on GitHub

**Red** - closed issue on GitHub

If you open an issue, at the top left corner, there would you find this

[image: opened]

and

[image: closed]

---

Also, if you hover over these icons on the issue listing page, then the pop-up would state what the type of issue is - opened/closed

Comment: And looking at the HTML source shows that the icon's class includes `octicon-issue-opened open`.

@Ken I recommend you accept this answer.

@mnestrorov Unfortunately, when I hovered over the icon, I did not see a pop-up or tooltip. Perhaps they've changed things?

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Both on the ticket page and individual ticket pages, I can hover over these icons and see a very small pop-up saying something like "Status: Closed" or "Closed Issue". Maybe it's just my browser? But you reminded me of something - the Github Issues search bar has `is:opened` and `is:closed`. This is a great indicator for the meaning of these icons/colors

Comment: Oops, I was looking in the wrong spot. I was hovering my mouse over the icons as in the OP's picture. If I hover my mouse over the spot where your picture was taken, I see the tooltips. Thanks.